# PHP tor installation

Tags: php, proxy, tor

I have this code:

```
<?php
$ip = '127.0.0.1';
$port = '9051';
$auth = 'PASSWORD';
$command = 'signal NEWNYM';

$fp = fsockopen($ip,$port,$error_number,$err_string,10);
if(!$fp) { echo "ERROR: $error_number : $err_string";
    return false;
} else {
    fwrite($fp,"AUTHENTICATE \"".$auth."\"\n");
    $received = fread($fp,512);
    fwrite($fp,$command."\n");
    $received = fread($fp,512);
}

fclose($fp);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://whatismyip.org");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:9050");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

The problem is it doesn't work. I am running on windows not linux. And I downloaded the tor browser. I understand there was supposed to be some configuration where I set a password and a port. However that did not happen during the install.

Is there anyone familiar with tor. What am I missing?

Comment: "It doesn't work" What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: What problems do you run into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Tor does not listen on the control port, and you will also need to configure a password or specify it use CookieAuthentication.  If you are going to be scripting with Tor, you may want to download the expert bundle instead of the browser bundle.

These values need to go in the `torrc` file in the Tor `Data` directory.  See the [default sample torrc](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/config/torrc.sample.in).

First, generate a hashed password (note piping to `more` is necessary on Windows or you won't see any output):

```
C:\Path\To\Tor>tor.exe --hash-password PASSWORD|more
```

Copy the output that looks like `16:*BUNCH_OF_HEX_DIGITS*`

Next, you need to edit your config and add or uncomment the line with `ControlPort 9051` and add your hashed password.

```
ControlPort 9051
HashedControlPassword 16:YOUR_HASHED_PASSWORD_HERE
```

Then restart the daemon, make sure it is using the config file with these values, and try your code again.

See the [docs](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ControlPort) on the ControlPort and HashedControlPassword settings.

Perhaps overkill for what you are doing, but you may also be interested in this [PHP Tor library](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils) I made which you can use to interact with the Tor control port.

Using my library your code would look like:

```
<?php

use Dapphp\TorUtils\ControlClient;
use Dapphp\TorUtils\ProtocolError;
$tc = new ControlClient();

try {
    $tc->connect(); // connect to 127.0.0.1:9051
    $tc->authenticate(); // uses cookie authentication, can also use $tc->authenticate('password_here');
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    echo "Failed to create Tor control connection: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
}

try {
    echo "Sending NEWNYM signal to controller...";
    $tc->signal(ControlClient::SIGNAL_NEWNYM);
    echo "OK";
} catch (ProtocolError $pe) {
    echo $pe->getMessage();
}

$tc->quit(); // close control connection
```

Comment: thanks for the help, its a good start. I downloaded expert bundle, and hashed a pw. Now I cannot find any configuration file. It just has a few dll files, tor.exe, and a data folder with 2 ipgeo files. But no other files, came in a zip. NOTE: I am runing this on a Vista64 VM. PHP is running on WAMP64. I have no problems configuing the PHP side, but where is the config file that I need to set the port in?

Comment: It doesn't come with a config file, but you can start from the [sample](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/config/torrc.sample.in) linked in this answer.  A full list of options is [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en).  You can put the config file anywhere, and specify it by the `-f` option when running Tor (e.g. `tor.exe -f ..\Data\torrc`)

Comment: followed your instructions to the best of my ability, set up conf file with your example and put under Tor/Data. Ran tor -f Data/torrc from cmd prompt. Then used PHP code that I provided in my original question and got this error

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9051 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. ) in C:\wamp\www\temp.php on line 8
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0000 243208 {main}( ) ..\temp.php:0
2 0.0000 244272 fsockopen ( ) ..\temp.php:8
ERROR: 10061 : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: any thoughts on this?

Comment: note I used the unhashes pw in my php, should I have used the hashed version there as well?

Comment: ok, i figured out the problem, the torrc file was given the extension .txt by windows, I found this when I piped tor.ext output to more. I reran it with  -f Data/torrc.txt and it worked.

Comment: however there is now a new problem. The IP address does not change each time the script is run. I need to get a new IP each time the script is run. So if you have any thoughts, Sometimes I do get a new IP and sometimes the IPs stick for 2 or 3 times. Is this because of the amount of time between requests? Should I only run the script every 10 or 15 seconds or so?

Comment: Every time you send the NEWNYM signal you should get a different circuit resulting in a new IP.  I have tested this on the past using Windows and I always got a different IP.  When you send the signal, are you checking to see if it sends a `250 OK` response?  And depending on how much you are running this, based on Tor's limited number of exit nodes, it will probably repeat eventually since at any given time there are only around 1,000 exit nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in `C:\Path\To\Tor>tor.exe --hash-password PASSWORD|more`, "PASSWORD" needs to be replaced like the password you like.
Suppose you use "my_password" as your password.
Then use: `C:\Path\To\Tor>tor.exe --hash-password my_password|more` to generate a hashed password
In your code to switch identity, use $auth = '"my_password"';
Yes, with double quotes