# Issue indicates wrong HashedControlPassword in scrapy while it is exactly the one presents in torrc file

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, scrapy, tor

I have got these messages in my log file:

```
[scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
[stem] INFO: Error while receiving a control message (SocketClosed): empty socket content
...
[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.website.com/robots.txt>: Authentication failed: Password did not match HashedControlPassword value from configuration
...
stem.connection.IncorrectPassword: Authentication failed: Password did not match HashedControlPassword value from configuration
```

The problem is I copied and pasted the exactly the same one present in `torrc` file, I even tried with `16:` in it and without, but I obtain the same error.

So what is wrong?

Comment: `tor --hash-password testing` >> `16:7BAD07663A65C51260996FF6B3BDBD47535575878EDF5BF324BE0EFC3A`.  The actual password you need to use is testing, not the hashed password.

Comment: @drew010 honestly I managed by leting the method `authentificate()`  empty. It works now. But I am curious to know how to get what you are talking about because in every tutorial I saw they write `authentificate(password='tor_password')` but never precise how to obtain it. Besides what is the risk without password?

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32771558/892493) it shows how to generate a hashed control password on Windows, on Linux, just run the above command (`tor --hash-password "your password here"`).  The only risk of leaving it open is if it's a shared system, anyone else can control Tor without a password; or if somehow it was listening on a public interface, then it could be controlled by some 3rd party. Safe Cookie Authentication is also another option.

Comment: @drew010 Ok, now I see I must do what you told me to otbain the right password, copy as string in my `middlewares.py` and copy it in `torrc` file too then it worked well like without password but now it is safer, I tried and it worked. Thank you very much.